# Loading image slow laravel jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Please check my js code below. It is written for getting profile images from folder. I have getting profile images and it's displayed correctly.

I have a default image, If users have no profile image the default image will display.

My problem is when page refresh, If a user has profile image default image is showing initially(for a millisecond) and then profile image shows. How can I solve this. I think it's a loading problem from jQuery.

**test.js**

```
$(function () {

    $.get("/getDetails")
        .done(function (data) {
            $("#profile_image").css('background-image', 'url(/profile.png)');
            if (data.filename == 'Profile') {
                $("#profile_image").css('background-image', 'url(' + data.route + ')');
                $("#deleteProfileImage").show();
            }
    });

});
```

**html** page:

```
<div id="profile_image" style="background: url(/profile.png) no-repeat center center;">
```

**controller page**

```
public function show()
{
    $id                  = Auth::user()->id;
    $details             = User::select('id', 'created_at')->findOrFail($id);
    $encrypt             = md5($details->id.$details->created_at);
    $directories         = Storage::files($encrypt);                                             // Listout Files
    foreach($directories as $values){
        $split_folder_file = explode('/', $values);           //08d16e9f44699e9334834833c02b7b8e/Profile.png
        $splitted_file     = end($split_folder_file);         //Profile.png
        $explode_filename  = explode('.', $splitted_file);    //explode(Profile.png)
        $explode_name      = $explode_filename[0];            //Profile
        $file_extension    = $explode_filename[1];            //png
        if ($explode_name == 'Profile') {
            switch( $file_extension ) {
                case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
                case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
                case "jpeg":
                case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpeg"; break;
                default:
            }
            $file = Storage::disk('local')->get($encrypt.'/'.$splitted_file);
            return response($file, 200)
                ->header('Content-Type', $ctype);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass it as a variable from controller into view file... Use the php logic to return default or custom photo name.

Comment: Yes its a loading problem. Your css will display the default as bg. While the ajax is waiting for response, until the response not arriving, the background image will shown. Maybe on local and cached its a millisecond, but could be seconds too... Why are you loading image with ajax and not set by default?

Comment: So better thing is load image without ajax right?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(function () {

    $("#profile_image").css('background-image', 'url(/profile.png)');
    $.get("/getDetails")
        .done(function (data) {
            if (data.filename == 'Profile') {
                $("#profile_image").css('background-image', 'url(' + data.route + ')');
                $("#deleteProfileImage").show();
            }
    });

});
```

It was showing foe initial milliseconds because it's written in your code that it displays the default image first and then checks if the image is present for user and then replaces it with the default image.

I moved default image to the else condition so that its only showed when uploaded user image is not avaialble.

Comment: @Anish Choudhary, Thanks. But page refresh, for a millisecond time, no image shows. After page loads if a user has profile image that image will shows. My purpose is how can we saw image when page preload.

Comment: you want to show the default image before the page loads and then when the user image loads you want to replace user image with default image?